# Redux Thunk silently fails to update state

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

A child component has the following button code:

```
// SelectDonation.js
          <button
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              this.props.testThunk();
              console.log(store.getState());
            }}
          >Test thunks</button>
```

`this.props.testThunk()` does not update the state object. I connected Redux Thunk like so:

```
// reducer.js
import ReduxThunk from "redux-thunk";

const starting_state = {
  log_to_console : 0,
  donation_amount : 12,
  checkoutStep : 'selectDonation',
};

const reducer = (previous_state = starting_state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'thunkTest':
      return {
        ...previous_state,
        redux_thunk_test_var : action.payload
      };
    default:
      return previous_state;
  }
};

export default createStore(reducer, starting_state, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
```

I expect a new state property `redux_thunk_test_var` to display in state but it does not onClick. I do see the state variables with initial states in the console though.

Am I not passing down the thunk correctly? Here is App.js

```
// App.js
          {this.props.checkoutStep === checkoutSteps.selectDonation &&
           <SelectDonation
            dispatch_set_donation_amount = {this.props.dispatch_set_donation_amount}
            dispatchChangeCheckoutStep={this.props.dispatchChangeCheckoutStep}
             {...this.props}
           />
          }         
          </Modal>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const map_state_to_props = (state) => {
  return {
    log_prop : state.log_to_console,
    donation_amount : state.donation_amount,
    checkoutStep : state.checkoutStep,
  }
};

const map_dispatch_to_props = (dispatch, own_props) => {
  return {
    dispatch_set_donation_amount : amount => dispatch(set_donation_amount(amount)),
    dispatchChangeCheckoutStep : newStep => dispatch(changeCheckoutStep(newStep)),
    dispatchUpdateStateData : (stateData, stateVariable) => (dispatch(updateStateData(stateData, stateVariable))),
    testThunk
  }
};
```

The action thunk:

```
// actions.js
export const testThunk = () => {
    const testDelay = setTimeout(() => 'Set Timeout done', 2000);
  return (dispatch) => {
    testDelay.then((data) => dispatch({
      type: 'thunkTest',
      payload: data })
    )
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to *dispatch* the result of the `testThunk()` action creator.  Right now, you're just returning it, and not calling `dispatch(testThunk())`.

See [this gist comparing syntaxes for dispatching](https://gist.github.com/markerikson/6c7608eee5d2421966d3df5edbb8f05c) to help understand the issue better.

The best way to fix this is to use [the "object shorthand" form of `mapDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object).  As part of that, I suggest changing the prop names to remove the word "dispatch", which lets you use the simpler ES6 object literal syntax:

```
const map_dispatch_to_props = {
    set_donation_amount,
    changeCheckoutStep,
    updateStateData,
    testThunk,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
conponentDidMount() {
  this.props.testThunk();
}

const map_dispatch_props = {
  testThunk
}


//action creator 

const fetch = (data) => ({
  type: 'thunkTest',
  payload: data
})


const fakeFetch = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve('Set Timeout done'), 2000));

export const testThunk = () => (dispatch) => fakeFetch.then(data => dispatch(fetch(data)))
```